# Sending Gcode to LEGO Mindstorms X/Y plotter?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, lejos

I am building an x/y plotter out of LEGO Mindstorms. I would like it to read an SVG file on the EV3 Brick, convert it to Gcode, and draw the coordinates.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Parsing XML is expensive.  The EV3 doesn't have much memory or CPU for XML libraries.  I'd do the conversion to Gcode in Linux off of the EV3.  Then use wifi or Bluetooth to send the simplified instructions to the EV3.

Comment: Maybe you could collaborate with this guy: https://www.facebook.com/groups/legomindstorms/permalink/596979523783611/

Comment: If you are using Inkscape, it appears there is [this plugin](http://www.cnc-club.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=35) that allows you to export Gcode.  This is only part of a solution however.